# Querying latest version of NuGet package in Artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory

Using `api/search/latestVersion` I can query for the latest version of an artifact in artifactory. The format is apparently as follows:

`ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/search/latestVersion?g=GROUP&a=ARTIFACT&repos=REPO`

The group and artifact ID are required parameters.

I have published both Maven and NuGet packages. For the Maven package it is obvious what the group ID is, it appears in the "Module ID" field in the artifactory GUI. This field has the value "N/A" in the artifactory GUI for my NuGet package, however, and when I published the NuGet package with the following command line:

`dotnet nuget push --source ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/nuget/REPO PATH_TO_NUPKG`

I did not explicitly supply a "group".

1. Do all artifacts have groups?
2. If so, what group would my NuGet package have been assigned to?
3. If not, should I be using a different command line/REST API call to publish my NuGet package with a specified group?